# Why does Kubuntu love my secondary display so much?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, window-manager, kwin

I'm sorry that this question is not more concrete, but it describes the issue very well.

I've installed Kubuntu and although I have set up my two displays correctly and defined my primary display, Kubuntu still opens windows on the secondary display first and I constantly have to drag them back.

It doesn't appear that the window manager *"saves"* these positions in any way, so closing a window on one diplay doesn't ensure it will again be opened on that one.

This extends to the taskbar-menus like the network-info and clipboard, which *sometimes* even open on the secondary display while the panel stays on the primary.

What can I do to fix this? I've already tried different placement modes (smart, center, etc.), but they don't help. Also, I've tried to set no primary display, but that results in the panel moving to my secondary display, as well.

Somehow, Kubuntu just wants to have everything there.

Comment: I find it helps if you can arrange for the secondary monitor to be to the right of the primary, so that (0,0) in the framebuffer is displayed by the primary monitor. You shouldn't have to of course, but that is my experience. (Note 18.04 initially had other problems with having the secondary monitor to the right, so you may need 18.04.03 or the HWE.)

Comment: Hi B.Tanner, okay, here's the problem: My secondary monitor is actually *above* my primary display - I know this is an unusual setup, but I can't really change my workflow that easily anymore and Gnome & Xfce were generally fine with that, when configured correctly. It's just that Kubuntu doesn't seem to like it. I experimented a little and tried to ancor my panel at the bottom, etc., which I thought worked for a while, but it's not consistent. I defined a Window Rule that all normal windows should inititally be displayed on screen 1, which also helps a little, but not with dialog boxes/menus.